# FirebaseDynamicLinks.Instance is null after update from 60.1142.1 to 71.1615.0

Tags: firebase, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, firebase-dynamic-links

I was using FirebaseDynamicLinks in my Xamarin forms project (everything works fine) and I decided to update my nuget packages.. but after I update Xamarin.Firebase.DynamicLinks (and all dependencies) I got null after calling FirebaseDynamicLinks.Instance.
There was some major changes? Do I need to modify my code somehow after this update? Thanks for any help!

I found this in logs, so my google-services.json should be right, right?

```
FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
```

Xamarin.Android SDK Version: 9.3.0.23

Operating System & Version: Win 10, 1803

Comment: There is already a complain about this in the Xamarin GitHub, I'd suggest you to ask this kind of bugs there since here, we could barely give you an answer. https://github.com/xamarin/

Comment: @FedericoNavarrete I also ask on official Xamarin [forum](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/162547/firebasedynamiclinks-instance-is-null-after-update-from-60-1142-1-to-71-1615-0). But I did not get the answer there also.. this was just a backup.

Comment: The most important in my experience is the GitHub and report it as a Bug since this is not exactly a coding error most of the times. One thing would be that you program it wrongly, but I have faced similar issues when I'm upgrading these libraries.

Answer (score 1):

So if not necessary now, suggest downgrading to previous version of **Xamarin.Firebase.DynamicLinks**. Maybe there are something not incompatible or new methods not be used correctly.

Comment: @Pavol Yeah , If you are not in a hurry to use the new version, you can update it after a while to see if there is still a problem, and you can still update it here.